# spongework of the brain

Tags: word-meaning

What does the word "spongework" means? I have found it here: http://www.morningstarchapel.org/articles/Sight-2.htm

*The eye sends, as we saw, into the cell-and-fibre forest of the brain throughout the waking day continual rhythmic streams of tiny, individually evanescent, electrical potentials. This throbbing streaming crowd of electrified shifting points in the ***spongework*** of the brain bears no obvious semblance in space pattern, and even in temporal relation resembles but a little remotely the tiny two-dimensional upside-down picture of the outside world which the eyeball paints on the beginnings of its nerve fibers to the brain. But that little picture sets up an electrical storm. And that electrical storm so set up is one which effects a whole population of brain cells. Electrical charges having in themselves not the faintest elements of the visual - having, for instance, nothing of "distance," "right-side-upness," nor "vertical," nor "horizontal," nor "colour," nor "brightness," nor "shadow," nor "roundness," nor "squareness," nor "contour," nor "transparency," nor "opacity," nor "near," nor "far," nor visual anything - yet conjure up all these.*

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Spongework** is an adjective to describe the **topology** of the brain, that it is not **solid** *per se* but consists of **structures** resembling a **sponge**: not smooth but **convoluted** with many **irregular** connections yet is mainly **interconnected** as a sponge is connected. It may also be an allusion to the **absorbancy** of a sponge and how **fluids can flow freely yet be held** within a sponge.

> **sponge** is the metaphor for comparison
>   **works** describes that it is a network or complex of ***sponges***

Answer (score 1):

*Spongework* is not a common word. The OED lists it as a compound ('sponge-work') of *sponge*, and shows two examples from the 19th century, and gives no definition. GloWBe (the corpus of global web-based English) has no examples at all.

Nonetheless, it is easy to understand in context, as an analogous term to "network", but with the density of a sponge rather than a net.